# Prevent page creation for a published custom content type

Tags: views, nodes, display-suite

I have a Drupal 8 custom content type that is used in views only.  I would like to prevent this type from creating a web page for content that is published.

Answer (score 1):

One easy method would be to add [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module and set it to "Page Not Found" when that content types view route is accessed.